# Need to read repeating values in an XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML that's in an XDocument that I need to parse:

```
<RESPONSES>
  <RESPONSE STATUS="OK">
     <ALBUM>
        <GN_ID>63074689-EDADA0FEDE93683CA03C6D38520A4D88</GN_ID>
        <ARTIST>Green Day</ARTIST>
        <TITLE>American Idiot</TITLE>
        <PKG_LANG>ENG</PKG_LANG>
        <DATE>2004</DATE>
        <GENRE NUM="105222" ID="35474">Punk</GENRE>
        <TRACK_COUNT>13</TRACK_COUNT>
        <TRACK>
           <TRACK_NUM>1</TRACK_NUM>
           <GN_ID>63074690-456E41C113DC8354DC6B25421F2C7989</GN_ID>
           <TITLE>American Idiot</TITLE>
        </TRACK>
        <TRACK>
           <TRACK_NUM>2</TRACK_NUM>
           <GN_ID>63074691-70EFB1E8EB31B5296D5822E55343EFA9</GN_ID>
           <TITLE>Jesus Of Suburbia / City Of The Damned / I Don&apos;t Care / Dearly Beloved / Tales Of Another Broken Home</TITLE>
        </TRACK>
        <URL TYPE="COVERART" SIZE="THUMBNAIL" WIDTH="75" HEIGHT="75">http://akamai-b.cdn.cddbp.net/cds/2.0/cover/0A1A/BABF/DEBC/CF21_thumbnail_front.jpg</URL>
        <URL TYPE="ARTIST_BIOGRAPHY">http://web.content.cddbp.net/cds/2.0?id=E1DA4CCF2BBE645C&amp;client=10395648&amp;class=biography&amp;type=text/plain&amp;tag=02vq7D8a8HkrfJ4rWglsq09xYTY0H7Fb.YOadB73lz1-z3EWy.dWzCVA</URL>
     </ALBUM>
   </RESPONSE>
</RESPONSES>
```

I can tell the number of tracks based on the  tag, but other than that the number of tracks will vary by album. Here's my existing C# code to parse the XDocument:

```
   var albums = new List<Album>();
        try
        {
            albums = (from item in inputDoc.Descendants("ALBUM") //.Elements("GN_ID")

                      select new Album
                          {
                              AlbumId = (string)item.Element("GN_ID"),
                              ArtistName = (string)item.Element("ARTIST"),
                              AlbumName = (string)item.Element("TITLE"),
                              TrackCount = (int)item.Element("TRACK_COUNT"),
                              Year = (string)item.Element("DATE"),
                              Genre = (string)item.Element("GENRE"),
                              CoverArt = item.Elements("URL").First(u => u.Attribute("TYPE").Value == "COVERART").Value.ToString(),
                              Biography = item.Elements("URL").First(u => u.Attribute("TYPE").Value == "ARTIST_BIOGRAPHY").Value.ToString()

                          }).ToList();



        }
```

And here's the structure that I'm reading into:

```
namespace MusicApp.Model
{
    public class Album
    {
        public string ArtistName { get; set; }
        public string AlbumId { get; set; }
        public string AlbumName { get; set; }
        public int TrackCount { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public string CoverArt { get; set; }
        public string Biography { get; set; }

        // Navigation properties
        public ICollection<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
    }
    public class Track
    {
        public string TrackId { get; set; }
        public int TrackNumber { get; set; }
        public string TrackName { get; set; }
        public string AlbumId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to parse the tracks (given that there's no way in advance to know how many there will be in a given response. Can someone please help me out with this?

Oh - and while I'm at it, how do I convert the "Ampersand-apos;" to an apostrophe (other than a string.replace()).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add

```
Tracks = item.Elements("TRACK")
            .Select(t=> new Track{
                TrackNumber = (int)t.Element("TRACK_NUM"),
                TrackName = (string)t.Element("TITLE"),
                TrackId = (string)t.Element("GN_ID"),
            }).ToList()
```

to your code...

So the whole code will be

```
var albums = (from item in inputDoc.Descendants("ALBUM") 

            select new Album
            {
                AlbumId = (string)item.Element("GN_ID"),
                ArtistName = (string)item.Element("ARTIST"),
                AlbumName = (string)item.Element("TITLE"),
                TrackCount = (int)item.Element("TRACK_COUNT"),
                Year = (string)item.Element("DATE"),
                Genre = (string)item.Element("GENRE"),
                CoverArt = item.Elements("URL").First(u => u.Attribute("TYPE").Value == "COVERART").Value.ToString(),
                Biography = item.Elements("URL").First(u => u.Attribute("TYPE").Value == "ARTIST_BIOGRAPHY").Value.ToString(),
                Tracks = item.Elements("TRACK")
                        .Select(t=> new Track{
                            TrackNumber = (int)t.Element("TRACK_NUM"),
                            TrackName = (string)t.Element("TITLE"),
                            TrackId = (string)t.Element("GN_ID"),
                        }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks LB - that works great! One remaining question: How do I populate the AlbumId in Tracks (which is a foreign key back to Album->AlbumId? Oh - and while I'm at it, how do I convert the "Ampersand-apos;" to an apostrophe (other than a string.replace()).

Comment: @user3171260 a) You already did that `(string)item.Element("GN_ID")`, Just repeat it in *Track block*. b) for `&apos;` you don't have to do anything special. xml parsers can handle it.